# Where can I find data for fast radio bursts like FRB 180916?

Tags: fast-radio-bursts

Where can I find Strength over Time for FRB 180916? 
Or at least day+time of remarkable events.

Is there some good data for other FRB that hit the earth for the last 2 years?

Answer (score 2):

There are parameters from the data listed [here](http://frbcat.org) There is a [site](https://www.facebook.com/BerkeleySETI/posts/400-tb-of-raw-data-on-the-first-repeating-fast-radio-burst-are-now-available-for/1141566812691138/) with raw data for FRB 121102, another repeating FRB, but the data set is 400 TB. The first site has links and may take you to the site where the data is stored. There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_radio_burst) with your specific FRB listed among others. The sources listed for 180916 may take you to the data site.

Comment: Thank you. In the first site there is nothing more recent than 11/2019. 400 tb is a little too much for me :(. I had no particular interest in astronomy and I'm not familiar with the terms so I'm looking for something "synthetic" a bit like a seismograph. I have a particular interest for FRB 180916 because of its period of 4 + 12 days and I'd really liked to know if/when we're in a period of strong "activity".